# Quicksort using Lomuto partition scheme in C

Tags: algorithm, c, array, sorting, quick-sort

This is my implementation of the divide-and-conquer Quicksort algorithm using the [Lomuto partition scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme) in C. This is part of a personal project and I'm following Linus Torvalds's [coding style](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html).

```
void swap(int *i, int *j)
{
    int tmp = *i;
    *i = *j;
    *j = tmp;
}

int partition(int *arr, int l, int r)
{
    int pivot = arr[r];
    int i = l;
    for (int j = l; j < r; ++j) {
        if (arr[j] < pivot) {
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
            ++i;
        }
    }
    swap(&arr[i], &arr[r]);
    return i;
}

void quicksort(int *arr, int l, int r)
{
    if (l >= r)
        return;

    int i = partition(arr, l, r);

    quicksort(arr, l, i - 1);
    quicksort(arr, i + 1, r);
}
```

The function `void quicksort(int *arr, int l, int r)` can be called like this:

```
int arr[] = {4, 1, 0, 2, 5, 3, 8, 9, 7, 6};
size_t arrlen = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
quicksort(arr, 0, arrlen - 1);
```

Comment: HI @andySukowsiBang - partition function doesn't seem to be correct ...  It always does a swap on the first element with itself ... should it perhaps be `for (j = l+1;`

Comment: @MrR You are partially right. The first element is swapped with itself, but the reason why the for-loop needs to start with `j = l` is that `++i` has to be reached if the first element is smaller than `pivot`.

Comment: @MrR Is there something else that could be optimized?

Comment: @AndySukowskiBang Anything unnecessary is always a problem.  What happens for bad inputs - e.g. negative numbers, null value for `arr`,  `&arr[offset]` might be slower than using pointers directly [depends on your platform & compiler].  Is it really the intention for partition to always do at least one swap (whenever l < r).

Answer (score 1):

Check for sizes of arrays that are less than 2, in that case there is no need to swap. You can also check whether i == j the condition that arr[j] < pivot.